# Deriving Kepler's First Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am trying to derive Kepler's first law and in the process,

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question. Please do not post scans of math, especially handwritten math.

Comment: Why did you suggest an edit to replace my answer with a link to screenshot of my answer? There are answers full of math all over this forum, it isn't unusual for that. If you think my answer is correct, just accept it. After this much time, your professor has probably already told you whether that is what the problem was trying to show.

Answer (score 1):

Take your

$$
\frac{1}{r} = B\cos(\theta) + \frac{GM}{h^{2}}
$$

and invert to

$$
r = \frac{1}{B\cos(\theta) + \frac{GM}{h^{2}}}
$$

Now just redefine $B$ to be a factor of $GM/r^{2}$ as

$$
B = e\frac{GM}{h^{2}}
$$

and rewrite with the substitution

$$
r = \frac{\frac{h^{2}}{GM}}{e\cos(\theta) + 1}
$$

Note that since

$$
h^{2} = \frac{GMe}{B}
$$

it can be rearranged as

$$
r = \frac{\frac{e}{B}}{1 + e\cos(\theta)}
$$

so

$$
d = \frac{1}{B}
$$

and

$$
r = \frac{ed}{1 + e\cos(\theta)}
$$

I'll make note that I generally do not see the orbit equation in this form (specifically the numerator, the denominator is always like that).